# How can I resolve issues connecting to HP-ENVY-5530 printer via CUPS in 18.10?

Tags: printing, 18.10, cups-lpd

I hope you didn't click here thinking I had the answer. I'm so lost right now.

I upgraded my system to 18.10 and I've been loving it, except now I cannot connect to my printer. It is a Wireless LAN connected printer and I don't have the option to connect to it via USB. When I was running 18.04 I had no issues, but when I upgraded I couldn't print. I now get a CUPS error that reads:

```
There was an error during the CUPS operation: 'server-error-internal-error'
```

So I removed the printer in settings, rebooted, and tried to add it again after I entered these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install cups --reinstall
sudo service cups restart
```

I got the same error.

Being a total noob, I thought maybe this was a bug because of the upgrade. So I did a clean install of 18.10 from a fresh download, and I'm getting the same error. I have tried to manually find the drivers for my printer but none worked. I really don't want to go back to 18.04 but man, I'm over here logging into my Windows machine just to print. That is sooooo sad.

The printer is: HP-ENVY-5530 series

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What makes you believe that it's a driver problem? Few network printers use drivers (except internally within the printer, of course).

Answer (score 1):

I actually fixed the issue using the GUI. When you add a printer in 18.10, choosing what seems to be your printer will result in the error. The way I added my Wireless LAN printer is I removed all of them and then added it by waiting for the list to fully populate and enter the actual IP address of the printer. It came up as a different name and now I have 2 printers listed under Settings > Devices > Printers but either one works.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue with Linux Lite OS (think it's based off Ubuntu 18.10) and a Canon MG6300. This thread was a big help. Here's what worked for me...

1. (With printer on) Go to Applications > System > Printers
2. Click 'Add Printers'. Click the down arrow by 'network printers', and wait for the list to populate.  Once it does, note the IP address of the wireless printer to add.
3. Click 'Find network printer' and enter the IP address from step #2.  A list of IP addresses should come up.  The first one, in my case was, IPP:(xxx.xxx.x.xxx).  Select this and click 'Forward.
4. Select the make and model for the printer.  If there are options for the drivers, select the one with 'Gutenprint'.  From the printer should be added, but if one tries to print a test page, an error message comes up. So...
5. Go to 'Settings' for the newly added printer.  Under 'Device URI', select change.  Click 'Find Network Printers'.  Now click the printer that we got the IP address from in step #2.
6. Go to 'Policies'. Select the 'Enabled' check box, and click 'Apply'.  Now, the printer should print the test page, and hopefully be good to go.

Hope that might help.  Was great to have the pointers in this thread.

With metta